# "With" instead of "and" for second author in biblatex chicago author-date

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biblatex-chicago

This might just be due to my inability to search the internet/manual for the right term, but maybe someone can point me in the right direction ...

What's the right way to achieve a correct citation of a work that is authored by "Michael Smith with Robert Miller"? 
This is sometimes the case for second authors that contribute significantly less to a given work. So "with replaces the "and" that joins both authors.

It should show up in author-date format in in-text citations as:

> surrounding text (Smith **with** Miller 2019) ...

and in the bibliography as:

> Smith, Michael, **with** Robert Miller. 2019. *Booktitle*. ...

Comment: I _think_ you could use `\authortypedelim`, but I'm not sure about the details.

Comment: In theory it should be easy enough to replace "and" with "with" (but `biblatex-chicago` is quite a complex style, so it might be trickier than I think at the moment), but that is not enough if you have several primary or several secondary authors.